# Why PHP function header() doesn't work with images on a remote server?

Tags: php, apache

I have this code

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE');
use app\components\FilesHandler;

$mimeType = FilesHandler::getType();
header("Content-Type: $mimeType");
echo FilesHandler::getFile();
```

And on the localhost machine an image has CORS headers, although it hasn't on a remote server.
How can I fix this?

---

Response headers from the remote server

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=315360000
Content-Length: 1521987
Content-Type: image/png
Date: Fri, 31 Jul 2020 05:07:17 GMT
ETag: "5f239615-173943"
Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 31 Jul 2020 03:55:01 GMT
Server: nginx
```

Response headers from the localhost

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: image/png
Date: Fri, 31 Jul 2020 03:53:10 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=120, max=1000
Server: Apache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Xdebug-Profile-Filename: D:\traces\cachegrind.out.13336
```

Comment: Please be more clear about your situation. What do you meant by "work" in your situation (what do you expect to see)? And what did you see instead?

Comment: @KoalaYeung I want to see CORS headers in the browser's "Network" section when I get an image (image.png for example), and I see headers on my local machine, but if I use a remote server, I don't see it

Comment: Are you accessing your remote machine directly? Or is it behind some sort of reverse proxy server (e.g. Cloudflare, Squid, Heroku)? Sometimes those proxy service messes with the header a bit.

Comment: @KoalaYeung No, I am not.  It's a direct get request through url

Comment: Can you show us the header result from curl / Postman?

Comment: @KoalaYeung I've added responses above

Comment: The header seems to imply that it is a direct nginx response rather than a PHP response. Please try to modify your PHP response with some plain text output instead of the file content (on the same URL). See if you still see the file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218952/discussion-between-evgeny-musonov-and-koala-yeung).